# How to select element nested inside targeted class using jquery

Tags: jquery

It seems like this question has been asked but I can't nail down the answer. How do I use jquery to target all anchor tags nested deep inside a div tag with the class "newTab"?

I have tried this code:

```
$('.newTab a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

and this code:

```
$('.newTab').find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

and neither work.

The anchor tag is nested 10+ div tags deep. I am working with Wordpress and can't edit the HTML directly. I am inserting the jquery using the headers and footers plugin. It is working as I can see it in the source code. As is evident in the jquery, I am trying to get links nested in a div tag with a class of "newTab" to open in a new tab.

Comment: Either should work.  What does `$('.newTab a').length` show?

Comment: Sorry but I am a jquery noob and still pretty fresh at web development. Should I run this in the console or add it to the header?

Comment: Console is the easiest way to tinker and debug with javascript.

Comment: I get this if I run it in the console

Comment: VM5373:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: Do you have jquery loaded on the page?

Comment: I assume. Should I turn it on somehow?

Comment: Well, don't assume, look at the source and see if you have jquery.js loaded

Comment: As I know, Wordpress typically preloaded jquery, not with `$` as caller, but `jQuery`

Comment: Sorry. Yes, jquery.js and jquery-migrate.min.js

Comment: OK, with Wordpress you need to use `jQuery('selector')` instead of `$('selector')`.

Comment: Ok, so doing the substitution for .length worked in the console and it returned a value of 1. Doing the substitution in the original header code did nothing

Comment: So it's only finding one anchor tag inside of .newTab.  Does that sound right?  Are you sure those anchor tags are inside that div and aren't in an iframe or something.

Comment: Yes, I can add a second and see what happens, and they are inside the div tag and not an iframe.

Comment: I added two more anchors and it returned a value of 3 so I guess it does target the right elements. Now the question is why they aren't opening in a new tab? Any idea on how to troubleshoot that?

Comment: You can inspect the elements and make sure the attribute is added.  If the attribute of target is set to _blank, it should be opening in a new tab.

Comment: If I run the .attr code in the console it works. I can see it at the top of the page in the source code but it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Do I need to define it as jQuery or something?